# Most efficient way to store numbers as strings inside a table

Tags: matlab

I want to store efficiently some numbers as strings (with different lengths) into a table. This is my code:

```
% Table with numbers
n = 5;
m = 5;
T_numb = array2table((rand(n,m)));

% I create a table with empty cells (to store strings)
T_string = array2table(cell(n,m));

for i = 1:height(T_numb)
   for ii = 1:width(T_numb)
      T_string{i,ii} = cellstr(num2str(T_numb{i,ii}, '%.2f'));
   end
end
```

What could I do to improve it? Thank you.

Comment: So, the input is `(rand(n,m))`, that is a 2D matrix, right?

Comment: Yes. It could any another 2D matrix input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to the function `cell2table` right now, but using the undocumented function `sprintfc` might work well here (check [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) for details).

For instance:

```
%// 2D array
a = magic(5)

b = sprintfc('%0.2f',a)
```

generates a cell array like this:

```
b = 

    '17.00'    '24.00'    '1.00'     '8.00'     '15.00'
    '23.00'    '5.00'     '7.00'     '14.00'    '16.00'
    '4.00'     '6.00'     '13.00'    '20.00'    '22.00'
    '10.00'    '12.00'    '19.00'    '21.00'    '3.00' 
    '11.00'    '18.00'    '25.00'    '2.00'     '9.00'
```

which you can convert to a table using `cell2table`.

So in 1 line:

```
YourTable = cell2table(sprintfc('%0.2f',a))
```

Comment: Awesome! And then a call to `cell2table`!

Comment: Yep! Oops I forgot to mention it haha I'll add the note thanks :) +1 for you as well! I didn't know about `strtrim` that's nice.

Comment: I don't think your approach needs strtrim.

Comment: Oh I don't think either; I was referring to your answer lol :)

Comment: Sure you're welcome! I like `sprintfc` quite a lot. Be aware that since its undocumented it might not work in future releases...anyhow have fun!

Comment: Oh and I just had a look at a question you asked a few days ago. You might want to check the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be quite fast -

```
T_string = cell2table(reshape(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(A(:),'%.2f'))),size(A)))
```

Or with `regexprep` to replace `strtrim` -

```
cell2table(reshape(regexprep(cellstr(num2str(A(:),'%.2f')),'\s*',''),size(A)))
```

Here, `A` is the 2D input numeric array.

Comment: I didn't remember about `cellstr`! Quite handy